# Window Location Pathname with Multiple Directories

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location, pathname

I'm sure this very easy, but I am having trouble writing this path correctly. I have no problems triggering the command using:

```
if(window.location.pathname.match(/^\/Home-Blog/)) {$('#maincolumn').remove();}
```

But for another case, I need the pathname to be longer, with the following directory:

```
/Home-Blog/CategoryBlogID
```

Any way I try to insert it, it doesn't seem to work. How do I plug in the path to "CategoryBlogID"?

Thank you!

Comment: is `CategoryBlogID` a string or will you replace that with a random number?

Comment: That's the string exactly

Comment: both `"/Home-Blog/".match(/^\/Home-Blog/)` and `"/Home-Blog/CategoryBlogID".match(/^\/Home-Blog/)` return the matched portion of the string, not sure I understand the question...

Comment: The "/" in between seems to break it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally sure I understand your question, but if you want to match

- /Home-Blog
- /Home-Blog/
- /Home-Blog/CategegoryBlogID

this RegExp should do the trick:

```
"/Home-Blog/CategoryBlogIDs".match(/^\/Home-Blog(\/)*(CategoryBlogID)?$/)
```

`/^` start of string

`\/` a forward slash

`Home-Blog` the text "Home-Blog"

`(\/)*` a forward slash zero or more times (will also match /Home-Blog////CategoryBlogID) because of this

`(CategoryBlogID)?` the string "CategoryBlogID" zero or one times

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references

Comment: Seems to work fine like that, thanks...but then I realized if(window.location.pathname.match('/Home-Blog/BlogCategoryID')) {$('#maincolumn').remove();} Works fine too